# Watering Flowers and Handling Post during long periods of absence: any multinational firm to handle this in any country?

Tags: europe, planning, security

I know there is the question [Preparing home for your trip](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9176/preparing-home-for-your-trip) but we have done everything mentioned there such as the arrangement with post-office.

My friend is absent for a longer period of time and we are trying to find a solution to water her flowers and get her unusual post. We are trying to find some sort of place-independent solution such as some multinational firm to handle this kind of absences just to keep places in order and check everything is fine. Basically, we need some someone to check places every month or so -- and perhaps fetch post or something like that.

What kind of services are there to handle this kind of situations? Some consult firm?

*P.s. We are mostly travelling in EU and the North 60 -- and we have time-consuming distances between one another.*

Comment: you and other friends of him can do that for him. When you're friends it should be no problem to do that once a month

Comment: Can the close voters provide a reason? I really not see why this should be closed.

Comment: I think it should be in tow separate questions.. watering flowers and post...

Comment: I voted to close, because the question is too broad. When it's a real question, it should be ask for one country, and not for any country

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. @hhh could you specify the country?

Comment: @RoflcoptrException done, the North 60 means the European countries around the latitude 60 such as Norway, Sweden and Finland.

Comment: @Dirty-flow it costs me over 150EUR in travel expenses to check the post and to water flowers. By this money, I am pretty sure I could get some to do it for me so I could save my time also -- it takes me about 10-20 hours' travel time to water flowers and and to fetch the post. 20*hour-salary+150EUR=...too high cost, cheaper to buy new plants or get a consult.

Comment: I agree with dirty flow. Specifying a city or region would even be better

Comment: What's wrong with good neighbours? Are there none you trust?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on the post but do you not have automatic watering systems for the flowers over there?  Such a system would obviously be too expensive for one trip but it sounds like this is someone who is often away.

Here such things are the norm.  There's a timer in the garage wired to valves buried in the yard (they're inside a box with a snap-on cover so they're easy to get to if need be) and then pipes feeding the locations that water is wanted.  It's fully automatic other than changing the settings seasonally.